# OpenGL and OpenGL ES performance comparison

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am buying the new Nexus 7 tablet and recently started learning some OpenGL so in few days I will be able to test OpenGL ES too.

As I understand it, many functions in ES are the same as in desktop OpenGL. So my question is, when I write the same application for both PC and Android device, using only ES supported methods, is the performance comparable? I mean I build the same SDL+OpenGL app for both android and on notebook, rendering the same graphics (on same resolution probably) can I compare the FPS and say how much faster my PC is, or does OpenGL ES work somehow else then normal one and therefor the results cant be compared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compare OpenGL and ES version.

First thing is that they will run on different OS (like Windows vs Android) and what is more important they will run on different GPU with different architecture. Too many factors to check.

You could compare different Android implementations for instance... or different PS OS'es or PS GPUs.

Comment: I agree, there are too many things that are different for the comparison to be of any value. You could try running in a hardware accelerated VM (such as [Genymotion](http://genymotion.com/)) on the **same** laptop, for a somewhat closer comparison - but even that would be a less than ideal comparison.